# Gradle Dependency rsolution in Android

Tags: android, gradle

So let's say our app uses the library "A" version 1.0
App use an SDK which has the same library "A" version 2.0

Now if we found out that A version 1.0 has a bug lets say log statement on a method and in version 2.0 it is removed.

So during runtime gradle will resolute to the max dependency version and in the final code we will not find the log statement printing anything.Right?

So i am trying to check how gradle resolution works

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer is that gradle dependency resolution takes the latest version.
So if sdk or the main app upgrades the SDK with a vulnerability fix the entire code will reflect the change.
https://github.com/rohangho/Dependency-Resolution

Here is MainChecker depends on StackQustionv2.0 and MyApplicationv1.0
MyApplication depends on StackQuestionv1.0